# Height of the expandable height

Tags: java, android, html, android-layout

This is my code for my java because the when it expands it doesn't expand to fit all of the text as it is too long, I need help to figure out how to make it expand to fit the text.

I have 2 Linear layout for my xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/color"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/color_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/color_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/marinabaysandroomicon"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clickme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Marina Bay Sand Hotel"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="To Travel: By Mass Rapid Transit (MRT):4 mins walk from Marina Bay on the North South Line and Circle Line.10 mins walk from Promenade on the Circle Line. Bayfront on the Circle Line and Downtown Line." />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="To Travel:By public bus:Services 97/97e, 106, 133, 502/502A, 518/518A,NR1 (Available on Fridays, Saturdays and eve of Public Holidays),and NR6 (Available on Fridays, Saturdays and eve of Public Holidays)."
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="To Travel: By water taxi:Water taxis can be taken from Grand Copthorne Water Front, Raffles Landing Side, Boat Quay, River Side Point and Robertson Quay to Marina Bay Sands.Ticket ranges from 4S$ to 16S$."
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/textView7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Rating 4.5/5.0"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Address:10 Bayfront Ave, 018956"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Price: S$729 - S$5,899 per night"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

```js
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
 LinearLayout mLinearLayoutHeader;
 ValueAnimator mAnimator;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandable);
     //mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  mLinearLayoutHeader = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
  
  //Add onPreDrawListener
  mLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                mLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        
                final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
          final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
          mLinearLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

          mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
                return true;
            }
        });
  
  
  mLinearLayoutHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mLinearLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                 expand();
                }else{
                 collapse();
                }
            }
        });
 }
 
 
 private void expand() {
  //set Visible
  mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  
  /* Remove and used in preDrawListener
  final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  mLinearLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
  mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
  */
  
  mAnimator.start();
 }
 
 private void collapse() {
  int finalHeight = mLinearLayout.getHeight();

  ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);
  
  mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
    //Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
    mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   
   @Override
   public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
   }
  });
  mAnimator.start();
 }
 
 
 private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {
  
  ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);
  
  
  animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
    //Update Height
    int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mLinearLayout.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = value;
    mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
   }
  });
  return animator;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I not misunderstand your question and your needing, if you are filling those linearlayout dynamic you should put the android:layou_height=wrap_content.

That way the linearlayout will grow depending the views inside it.

Check this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Updates:

Sorry for the misunderstand your layouts does not have any problem just change the widthSpec and heightSpec on your OnCreate method to:

final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mLinearLayout.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mLinearLayout.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

Verify here what that value mean: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html

That worked for me if you have any problem please provides some photos for see how is being displayed.

Comment: Doesn't seems working and it's the same.  I have updated my code.

Comment: Thankyou. I don't have any problem anymore.